# LARAVEL - problemas al leer fecha en datepicker desde tabla

Tags: html, laravel, bootstrap, datepicker

Tengo una tabla generada con infyom para laravel, y en la lista de registros deseo editar, cuando se muestran los datos para editar los campos, tengo dos campos de tipo fecha que no se muestran en sus respectivos datepicker por lo que ambos valores se mantienen nulos.

Esta es la imagen de la vista:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Acá dejo el código generado por infyom (archivo: fields.blade.php)

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    {!! Form::label('fechaingreso', 'Fecha ingreso:') !!}
    {!! Form::date('fechaingreso', null, ['class' => 'form-control','id'=>'fechaingreso']) !!}
</div>
@section('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#fechaingreso').datepicker(
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
            useCurrent: true
        })
    </script>
@endsection

<!-- Fechatermino Field -->
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    {!! Form::label('fechatermino', 'Fecha termino:') !!}
    {!! Form::date('fechatermino', null, ['class' => 'form-control','id'=>'fechatermino']) !!}
</div>
@section('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#fechatermino').datetpicker({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
            useCurrent: true
        })
    </script>
@endsection
```

Answer (score 0):

Para mostrar la fecha que ya tienes almacenada, debes utilizar la opción defaultDate, y pasarle la fecha como parámetro:

```
    $('#fechaingreso').datepicker(
        format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss',
        useCurrent: true,
        defaultDate: {{ $fechaingreso ?? false }}
    });
```

Revisa la documentación del datepicker: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/Options/#defaultdate

Comment: Hola Shaz!, agregué lo que indicas, pero al momento de editar el registro, me continúa mostrando la leyenda "dd-mm-aaaa" y no la fecha que traigo desde la base.

Comment: A mí me funciona sin problema, tal vez intenta sin el wrapper de Laravel Collective, o sea, utiliza html puro para escribir el campo y sus atributos.

Comment: No me manejo para nada con html, esto lo hice a partir de infyom que generó todo el código, de ahí el problema. Gracias Shaz por tu ayuda!

Comment: Sería bueno que aprendas html básico entonces.

Answer (score 0):

Espero que le sirva a alguien, ya solucioné el problema...
En la línea de código reemplacé el valor null por $solicitud->fechaingreso, lo mismo para el caso de $solictud->fechatermino.

En definitiva, el código quedó así:

```
<!-- Fechaingreso Field -->
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    {!! Form::label('fechaingreso', 'Fecha ingreso:') !!}
    {!! Form::date('fechaingreso', $solicitud->fechaingreso, ['class' => 'form-control','id'=>'fechaingreso']) !!}
</div>
@section('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#fechaingreso').datetpicker({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
            useCurrent: true    

        })
    </script>
@endsection

<!-- Fechatermino Field -->
<div class="form-group col-sm-6">
    {!! Form::label('fechatermino', 'Fecha termino:') !!}
    {!! Form::date('fechatermino', $solicitud->fechatermino, ['class' => 'form-control','id'=>'fechatermino']) !!}
</div>
@section('scripts')
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#fechatermino').datetpicker({
            format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
            useCurrent: true
        })
    </script>
@endsection
```